# Cannot post question due to some false time constraint

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I am using Stack Overflow. I just logged in and am trying to post a question by clicking the "Post Your Question" button, but it gives a pop-up saying "You can only post once every 90 minutes."
I didn't even post anything today. Why is this happening? This similar thing happened to me previously also.

Answer (score 9):

I guess someone within your organisation or school using a low-reputation account posted today. There is a threshold to prevent mass-asking of low-quality questions, and you hit the threshold.

This is not a bug: it is by design. Since some users share the same IP address, there is a filter not only on user name, but also on IP address.

So unfortunately you have to wait until the time is over, and then try to post again.

Also see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/245360) on this (see under *Asking*).